# Wordpress: Strip out content builder shortcodes

Tags: regex, replace, shortcode

I have a WP site with a lot of content (approx. 5000 posts). These posts contain (in `post_content`) obsolete shortcodes from a content builder, which I need to strip out for good:

```
[av_three_fifth first] [av_textblock size=“ font_color=“ color=“ av-medium-font-size=“ av-small-font-size=“ av-mini-font-size=“ admin_preview_bg=“] 
Nunc nec neque. Curabitur blandit mollis lacus. Quisque malesuada placerat nisl. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Vestibulum fringilla pede sit amet augue.

Maecenas vestibulum mollis diam. Cras id dui. Vestibulum ullamcorper mauris at ligula. Fusce commodo aliquam arcu. Donec interdum, metus et hendrerit aliquet, dolor diam sagittis ligula, eget egestas libero turpis vel mi.

Sed a libero. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada pretium. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed aliquam, nisi quis porttitor congue, elit erat euismod orci, ac placerat dolor lectus quis orci. Aenean posuere, tortor sed cursus feugiat, nunc augue blandit nunc, eu sollicitudin urna dolor sagittis lacus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Fusce id purus.
[/av_textblock] [/av_three_fifth]
```

Is there a chance that I can come up with a sophisticated regex to remove those strings? The problem is that many of those are very varied, so no "one fits all" solution here I fear...

TIA for your help / ideas!

Comment: why the downvote? and without explanation, too :-O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to "semi-solve" this via a free WP plugin which hides broken shortcodes: https://wordpress.org/plugins/hide-broken-shortcodes/

Thought I'd share it in case someone else needs this.